# Django DRF - Entire Other User Profile return in API call

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**I have a UserSerializer (I used a CustomUser model)**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
      model = CustomUser
      fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_typeA', 'is_typeB']
      read_only_fields = ['id', 'email', 'is_typeA', 'is_typeB']
```

**I have a profile model for each user type, and a serializer as well.**

```
class TypeASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = UserSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = TypeAProfile
    fields = ['user_id','user','course', 'ndex', 'created_at']
    read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at']

class TypeBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = UserSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = TypeBProfile
    fields = ['user_id', 'user', 'course', 'rating', 'created_at']
    read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'rating']
```

I have an endpoint to get the logged in users profile.

```
class MyProfile(APIView):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = get_user_profile(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
  
  def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_typeA:
      typeauser = TypeAProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
      user_updates = request.data.pop('user')
      serializer = TypeASerializer(typeauser, data=request.data, partial=True)
      serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      serializer.save()
      user_serializer = UserSerializer(typea.user, data=user_updates, partial=True)
      user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      user_serializer.save()
      return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.user.is_typea:
      typebuser = TypeBProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
      user_updates = request.data.pop('user')
      serializer = TypeBSerializer(typebuser, data=request.data, partial=True)
      serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      serializer.save()
      user_serializer = UserSerializer(typebuser.user, data=user_updates, partial=True)
      user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      user_serializer.save()
      return Response(serializer.data)
    serializer = UserSerializer(request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

My endpoint is : /profile.

This return:

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "is_typeA": false,
        "is_typeB": true
    },
    "course": "Udemy-123",
    "index": 2
    "created_at": "2022-04-12T01:43:49.091825Z"
}
```

I have added a Favourites Model - this is for users to favourite each other. TypeA users can favourite Type B users.

```
class Favourite(models.Model):
    typeA = models.ForeignKey(to=TypeAProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='favourites')
    typeB = models.ForeignKey(to=TypeBProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fans')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.typeB)
```

**The problem:**

I am trying to return a list of favourites on the Profile API call but so far I am unable to get it to make sense.

I added favourites to the TypeA profile Serializer:

```
class TypeASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = UserSerializer()
  favourites = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = TypeAProfile
    fields = ['user_id','user', 'course', 'handicap_index', 'created_at', 'favourites']
    read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at']
```

And it returns the emails of the users who are favourites, but I want it to return their entire profile.

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "is_typeA": false,
        "is_typeB": true
    },
    "course": "Udemy-123",
    "index": 2,
    "created_at": "2022-04-12T01:43:49.091825Z",
    "favourites": [
    "test1@email.com",
    "test2@email.com"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write:

```py
class TypeASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = UserSerializer()
  favourites = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_favourites(self, obj):
     return TypeBSerializer([favourite.typeB for favourite in obj.favourites.all()], many=True).data

  class Meta:
    model = TypeAProfile
    fields = ['user_id','user', 'course', 'handicap_index', 'created_at', 'favourites']
    read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at']
```

Comment: The first solution gives me the following error:
   
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `TypeBSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Favourite` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Favourite' object has no attribute 'user'.

Comment: @Steve Ok I have edited my answer